# C++ Tic-Tac-Toe using switch case

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

I was trying out a C++ code for the Tic Tac Toe program with help of classes . I am new to coding and would appreciate some help.This is what I have done till now.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int turn=1;
class abc
{
private:
int a[9];
char ch1,ch2;
public:


void accept()
{
    if(turn==1)
     {
     cout<<"\n\nPlayer 1 enter choice : ";
     cin>>ch1;
     turn=2;
     }
    else
    {
     cout<<"\n\nPlayer 2 enter choice :";
     cin>>ch2;
     turn=1;
     }
}

void layout()
{
a[0]=1;
a[1]=2;
a[2]=3;
a[3]=4;
a[4]=5;
a[5]=6;
a[6]=7;
a[7]=8;
a[8]=9;

cout<<"\n\n"<<"-----------"<<" "<<a[0]<<"     "<<a[1]<<"     "<<a[2]<<" -----------";       
cout<<"\n"<<"-----------"<<" "<<a[3]<<"     "<<a[5]<<"     "<<a[6]<<" -----------";
cout<<"\n"<<"-----------"<<" "<<a[6]<<"     "<<a[7]<<"     "<<a[8]<<" -----------";
}

void process ()
{
if (turn==1)
{

switch(ch1)
{
    case 1:     
    a[0]='x';
    break;

}
}
}

/*void check()
{
if(a[0]==a[1] && a[1]=a[2]
}
*/

};

int main()
{
abc def;
cout<<"-----------TIC - TAC - TOE-----------";
def.layout();
do
{
    do
    {
    def.accept();
    def.process();
    def.layout();       
    //def.check();
    }while(turn==2);

    }while(turn==1);

    return 0;
}
```

So , I can switch from player 1 to player 2 , I intend to use the process function for modifying the layout i.e if the turn 1 player enters 1 then the array should be layout should be modified accordingly . And basically I think I know the logic for the check function i.e a[0]==a[1] && a[1]=a[2] and the other 7 conditions . I just want to know how to use switch case in this condition.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It seems like you don't have a specific question yet, and you are hoping to have a discussion about this code.  Is that true?

Comment: If you are new to programming and still in learning process, do it right. First rule of programming is to write readable code: readable even for yourself. What I mean by readable? A program is an organized way of step by step description of an idea/process/task. So, you should be clear with what you say and how you say it. For example abd and def are horrible horrible class names. If you want other people to understand your code and help you, HELP THEM by at least writing something readable.

Comment: I'm sorry . I do understand that the class name and object name do not make any sense . And my question is , can how can I use switch case to change the value of the array .Let's say if the User 1 enters 1 as as his choice , I want a[0] set to x and similarly for User 2 using switch case , just I have no idea how to do it . The process and switch functions are still incomplete and I should have commented it too .

Answer (score 0):

As the comments on your question have implied, your code needs better formatting. However, to answer your question, you could do something along the lines of:

```
void process() {
    if (turn == 1) {
        a[ch1 - '0'] = 'x'; //char - '0' to convert char to int
    } else {
        a[ch2 = '0'] = 'o';
    }
};
```

As you can see, you don't really need a switch here. Just use their input to directly access the correct spot in the array.